# Including format instructions in CSV?

Tags: excel, csv

I have to write data in a csv format, but some of the users will edit that in excel and those have been complaining about the lack of cell formatting. Is there any way to include some instructions on how excel should format the cells, e.g. the same way you can tell excel the separator with an initial line with `SEP=,`?

Comment: Probably just save as an Excel file here.

Comment: Can you give an example of a value you'd like to format? This might help too, https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string

Comment: It's not about the value but the cells (edited the post now), e.g. once you have it open in excel, you can change cell width or make text bold, just stuff like that.